# How to retrieve xstring value from ABAP using RfcQuery?

Tags: s4sdk

I am wondering how a xstring should be retrieved from ABAP backend using RfcQuery.

```
final RfcQuery query = new RfcQuery(<myRFC>)...
Byte[] pdf = query.execute(erpEndpoint).get("EX_BLOB").getAs ??
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Found a workaround using base64 encoded string

Comment: Could you pls explain your workaround in more detail?

Comment: To give other users with a similar problem a better chance of solving it, please be so kind to provide the answer you found for your problem. Thanks.

Comment: The "workaround" is the following:
In ABAP: Export the xstring as a base64-encoded string. 
In Java: query.execute(erpEndpoint).get("EV_BLOB").asString(); Then you can decode it or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

As of now retrieving XSTRING values from an remote-enabled function module is not supported.

I'll edit this question if there is an update.